# Selenium IWebDriver Navigate().GoToUrl() not entering url or navigating to page

Tags: c#, firefox, visual-studio-2012, selenium, webdriver

I'm creating a new test project and can't think of anything else to try to resolve my issue.  I have another Selenium project that works as expected, and have compared the two to find differences.  But first, the main issue I'm running into.
In the setup I call Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("www.test.com");
No exception is thrown or anything else that would indicate there is a problem, the flow just moves to the next statement, but no Url is entered into the navigation bar, and so obviously the driver never navigates to any page.  The driver does start up a new firefox instance, but it stays blank.

When I compare this new project against an already working project, they seem identical for the most part.  Both projects have ...\packages\Selenium.WebDriver.2.37.0 & ...\packages\Selenium.Support.2.37.0 installed using NuGet package manager.
Both projects have identical references to the project in the .csproj file
--Working project
...
    
    
    
    
      ....\packages\Selenium.WebDriver.2.37.0\lib\net40\WebDriver.dll
    
    
      False
      ....\packages\Selenium.Support.2.37.0\lib\net40\WebDriver.Support.dll

--Unworking project
...
    
    
    
    
      ..\packages\Selenium.WebDriver.2.37.0\lib\net40\WebDriver.dll
    
    
      ..\packages\Selenium.Support.2.37.0\lib\net40\WebDriver.Support.dll

Neither project does anything else.  The constructor for both simply calls:
var WebDriver = new FirefoxDriver();

When I examine the WebDriver object, the only difference I can see is the WindowsHandles property.  The working project has:
WindowsHandles    Count = 1

The non-working project has:
WindowsHandles    {System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection}

I have no idea why they're different but as it's the only difference I can find, I'm thinking maybe that's the problem but I have no idea if that's really the case or how I'd fix it.
I've added a try/catch block around the WebDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl() and no exception is being caught.
Both projects target the .NET 4.0 framework.
Any help is greatly appropriated.

Comment: What version of Firefox? Any different on other browsers?

Answer (score 20):

I figured it out right after I finally broke down and decided to post on StackOverflow. My issue was `IWebDrivers` insists upon a passed in URL beginning with `http`. Once I prefixed my URL with that, it worked.

Comment: Seems like this is a very common problem. If the URL isn't well formed it doesn't navigate, I have a similar situation where I have ?#tab-reviews at the end of the URL. This works with ChromeDriver but not with PhantomJS driver. Thinking it might be a PhantomJS limitation...

Comment: Thanks - strangely the IE driver doesn't require the `http` prefix, which threw me off.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I was getting a strange behavior where, with the browser being visible, it worked just fine without the `http://`, but running it headless, it didn't work. Adding the `http://` made it work properly. (I'm using Chrome web driver)

Comment: @Darien Everett or anyone -  Will it work with https?  I ask because i have to pass some urls that begin with https using this.  Does anyone know?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple example how to do so:

1. Add NuGet package Selenium.WebDriver
2. Download chromedriver (https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/) or any other driver from http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/ (section Third Party Browser Drivers NOT DEVELOPED by seleniumhq)
3. Copy the file to your project directory in Visual Studio and set the following properties for the file:

   Build Action = None;
   Copy to Output Directory = Copy if newer

Once installed, try running the following example code:

```
var driver = new ChromeDriver();
var navigate = driver.Navigate();
navigate.GoToUrl("http://www.microsoft.com"); //works
navigate.GoToUrl("www.microsoft.com"); //does not work
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Also

```
navigate.GoToUrl("http:\\www.microsoft.com"); // "\\" instead of "//", wont work
navigate.GoToUrl("http://www.microsoft.com"); // that one works perfectly.
```

with backslashes instead of forward slashes wont work either... I've just spend about an hour, figuring this out.

URL address, correcly must be with forward slashes.

Answer (score 0):

Just concatenate on url "http://" and this problema is solved. o.O
I don't know why this error, but's solved.
Just do it !

Answer (score 0):

My issue with Navigate() not working was when driver focus is on the wrong tab (most commonly, if you've already opened another tab by clicking a "_blank" link on the current tab) and you are calling Navigate().GoToUrl().

Then you should be selecting the tab again in which you will change the url, like this:
C# example

```
var tabs = this.browser.WindowHandles;
this.browser.SwitchTo().Window(tabs[0]);
```